# Constraint Issue When Loading .sql file into Postgres DB

Tags: django, postgresql, relational-database, psql

I performed a `pg_dump` on the entirety of my production database, and tried to upload it locally on a newly migrated clean Postgres DB. When I do `psal db_name < data.sql`, I get errors like this

```
insert or update on table "vehicle_vehicle" violates foreign key constraint "vehicle_vehi_vehicle_make_id_265a8146_fk_vehicle_vehiclemake_id"
DETAIL:  Key (vehicle_make_id)=(788) is not present in table "vehicle_vehiclemake".
```

My questions are:

1. When a table with foreign keys is attempted to be loaded, and another table has foreign key relationships that hasn't been uploaded yet, does Postgres stop what it's doing and starts to load that table?
2. How does loading data tackle this issue? Is it on the user to dump the data table by table, and load them one at a time ?

Comment: Well, just to give you an idea, you disable foreign key constraints by executing [`ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE TRIGGER ALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html). But don't forget to enable them later. Be warned, that you can make quite a mess with this, but if you are sure about the integrity of your data, it should be safe to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pg_restore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgrestore.html) with `--clean` to restore your DB from scratch. If the following is a full dump, data should be inserted before foreign keys were set so you shouldn't have problems.